# Add new attribute to product images in Magento

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

Is it possible to add another text attribute to images in magento, same as the label attribute?
Actually, I want to have a select field next to all product images filled with the 'color' attribute values to specify which image is for which color.
We can add attributes via magento admin panel but they all appear as radio buttons like base image, small image & thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute for each color so that there is radio button next to image for each color. If you have 3 color(say red green blue), then create 3 attributes like red color image, blue color image, green color image. Then in image section you could check on appropriate radio button to identify to which color your image belong to.